# VBscript ends without user input

Tags: vbscript

I am having a problem with VB scripts on a Windows 7 computer.  When I try and run any *.vbs file, it runs the script but does not pause for user input.  The code below runs but it does not pause for the echo statement.  On other computers it will pause for the user to press the Ok button.  What do I need to change on the computer which does not allow it to pause?

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

strPath = "c:\temp"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
Wscript.Echo objFolder.Size
```

or

```
Input = InputBox("Enter Project Number: ")
Wscript.Echo Input
```

Answer (score 1):

Map your VBScript to wscript.exe instead of cscript.exe.

Right click -> Open With... -> Ensure "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" check box is checked -> Click the "Browse..." button -> "C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe" -> Open -> OK

Comment: The window still closes.

Comment: You see a black window briefly opening? Then it's still using cscript - something went wrong with associating it with wscript.

Comment: There is no black window.  It shows the wscript host windows but only for a short period on time and it closes.

Comment: @GreyHippo There is no such thing as a "wscript host window". What is the output of `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %t in ('assoc .vbs') do @ftype %t`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The same problem occurs.  When I say "wscript host window" I mean the window shown as a result of a wscript.echo call.

Comment: @GreyHippo Click *Start -> Run...*, enter "cmd.exe" and click "OK". In the command prompt enter the `for /f ...` command line and press `Enter`. What is the output?

Comment: @GreyHippo Did you try to run the command Ansgar Wiechers gave you? It's important to determine the problem.

Comment: I ran @AnsgarWiechers suggestion and the same problem occurs.

Comment: @GreyHippo Are you unable to launch a command prompt? Otherwise it's clearly not possible that you got the same problem when following my instructions.

Comment: I was able to launch the command prompt and I copied your code and substituted the name of my vbscript.  The vbscript started and ran but immediately opened and closed the "echo" window/box/display.

Comment: The script is using wscript.exe because I can see it in the task manager but again it closes after a second and wscript goes away.

Comment: @GreyHippo I'm talking about the command I suggested in the 4th comment from the top. Paste or type that command directly into the command prompt. Don't leave anything out, and don't add anything to it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, see my comment above

Comment: @GreyHippo The command I suggested does not use `wscript.exe` anywhere, and it also doesn't open any additional window/popup. Either you're doing something fundamentally wrong, or your system is severely compromised, in which case you should format and reinstall. This is all I can tell you with what little information you provided.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I misunderstood your code.  Here is the output VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*

Answer (score 0):

As the mapping to CScript is a good suggestion and should work, as an alternative you can use the [MsgBox statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) in your script. This shows a message box independently if you are running under CScript or WScript:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

strPath = "c:\temp"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
MsgBox objFolder.Size
```

Comment: What if I need to use an input box?